# In VBA Given an input box value, write a program that changes the font to italic for cells in a range below the given value

Tags: vba, excel

I've gotten fairly confused on this problem. The question as stated above asks you to write a program that gives an input box where you may enter a cutoff level. Once the cutoff level is given all values in the range on the sheet below that cutoff level need to be italicized. Where I get stuck is making the code select cells, not the whole range. Any suggestions?

### Assignment

The file Sales.xlsx contains sales data of a firm for its different regions in a given month. Write a macro that italicizes and changes the font color to blue for the months Region 8 had sales less than a cutoff level provided by the user in an InputBox. For example, if the user enters 10000 in the InputBox, the macro should search for the months where sales in Region 8 are less than 10000. Then, the macro should turn cells E9, F9, I9, J9, K9, and L9 to italic with blue font

### My attempt

```
Sub Homework7Problem2() 
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+b 
Dim Cutoff As String 
Cutoff = InputBox("Enter the cutoff level you would like to use", "CutoffLevel")
If Range("B2:M41").Cells < CutoffLevel Then 
    Range("B2:M41").Cells.Font.Italic = True 
    With Selection.Font 
        .Color = -4165632 
        .TintAndShade = 0 
    End With 
End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: How about giving us some piece of code first ?

Comment: Sorry never been on this site before, it was recommended to me by a friend. Here is the original question.
The file Sales.xlsx contains sales data of a firm for its different regions in a given month.
Write a macro that italicizes and changes the font color to blue for the months Region 8 had sales less than a cutoff level provided by the user in an InputBox. For example, if the user enters 10000 in the InputBox, the macro should search for the months where sales in Region 8 are less than 10000. Then, the macro should turn cells E9, F9, I9, J9, K9, and L9 to italic with blue font.

Comment: Sub Homework7Problem2()
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+b
    Dim Cutoff As String
    Cutoff = InputBox("Enter the cutoff level you would like to use", "CutoffLevel")
    If Range("B2:M41").Cells < CutoffLevel Then Range("B2:M41").Cells.Font.Italic = True
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = -4165632
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    End If
    
End Sub

Comment: Why does this need to be VBA? You could designate a specific cell to be your input box, and then use conditional formatting to accomplish this

Comment: No problem mate, but you should take a look at the rules to get started on StackOverflow, they are useful. Also you should edit your question to add your code in it and be sure to use the [code] tag :)

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework for you?

Comment: It needs to be VBA because this is for a class I am taking that specifies it as such. I already submitted my assignment with the given code for partial credit but the final exam is upcoming and I just wanted to crack this problem. And I'm sorry if I broke any of the rules :(

Comment: I am not asking anyone to do this for me, I have part of the code and the homework is already long passed. I'm just curious as to how to finish the code past the InputBox. I just don't know how to proceed writing the conditional statements

Comment: Fair enough, I missed the code you had put in the comments

Comment: On the left bottom of Excel there's a small button called "Record macro". Click on it, make the action manually and then stop it to see what is the code you wrote; 95% of your mark will be already there.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you'd need to loop over the cells and determine which ones meet the criteria (in this case, cells that are less than the cutoff). Once you have identified those cells, you can format them however you like.  I prefer to put them in to a range variable and then format all of the identified cells all at once at the end which is much faster than formatting each identified cell individually as you find it.  As you learn more VBA you'll find that this is considered good practice.

Here is the commented code:

```
Sub Homework7Problem2()

    'Declare Variables
    Dim rngSales As Range       'Range to store the Sales cells
    Dim SalesCell As Range      'Loop variable for rngSales
    Dim rngBelowTarget As Range 'Range to store cells that are below the target/cutoff
    Dim dTarget As Double       'Variable used to store the target/cutoff entered by the user

    'Define what cells to check
    Set rngSales = Range("B2:M41")

    'Reset formatting so that only cells below the new target will be formatted
    With rngSales
        .Font.Italic = False
        .Font.Color = vbBlack
    End With

    'Use Application.InputBox and set the Type parameter to 1 to force a number
    dTarget = Application.InputBox("Enter the cutoff level you would like to use:", "Cutoff Level", Type:=1)
    If dTarget = 0 Then Exit Sub   'User pressed cancel

    'Verify if there will be any matching cells
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngSales, "<" & dTarget) = 0 Then
        'If no matching cells, return error and exit the subroutine
        MsgBox "No months found to have sales less than [" & dTarget & "]", , "No Matches"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Loop though each cell in the range
    For Each SalesCell In rngSales.Cells
        If SalesCell.Value < dTarget Then
            'If a matching cell is found, add it to the rngBelowTarget variable
            If rngBelowTarget Is Nothing Then
                'This is the first cell found
                Set rngBelowTarget = SalesCell
            Else
                'This is for subsequent cells found, add them to the variable
                Set rngBelowTarget = Union(rngBelowTarget, SalesCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next SalesCell

    'Format cells that meet the condition
    With rngBelowTarget
        .Font.Italic = True
        .Font.Color = vbBlue
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do this, comparing the entire range to the cutoff-value as you've done won't work, but you can loop through the entire range and apply the formatting to any cell that fulfill the conditions:

```
Sub Homework7Problem2()
  ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+b
  Dim Cutoff As String
  Dim c As Range

  Cutoff = InputBox("Enter the cutoff level you would like to use", "CutoffLevel")

  For Each c In Range("B2:M41")
    If c < CLng(Cutoff) Then
      c.Font.Italic = True
      c.Font.Color = -4165632
      c.Font.TintAndShade = 0
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Alternately you could use a macro to apply somee conditional formatting to the range:

```
Sub Homework7Problem2()
  ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+b
  Dim Cutoff As String

  Cutoff = InputBox("Enter the cutoff level you would like to use", "CutoffLevel")

  With Range("B2:M41")
    ' First delete earlier conditional formatting, to avoid conflicts
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    ' Add new conditional formatting
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=" & Cutoff
    With .FormatConditions(1).Font
      .Italic = True
      .Color = -4165632
      .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
  End With
End Sub
```

I'd argue that it'd be much simpler to just apply the conditional formatting from the conditional formatting dialogue in Excel, but since the problem requires VBA, I suppose you may  get some use out of this.

Comment: I am no longer getting an error message but no cells are highlighted! Any idea what the problem might be? Thank you so much for your help also! I do generally apologize for my total ignorance, I'm not well versed in any code except some self taught HTML and Wikipedia mark up language.

Comment: Probably because the `Cutoff` variable is a string and the values in range B2:M41 are numbers so the comparison is failing due to mismatched data types.

Comment: @Crimsontide57 Yeah, I got the title of the inputbox and the variablename messed up, should be fixed now. I also made sure that I  attempt to convert the input to a `Long`.  You can still run into trouble though, if whoever inputs data enters something else than a number.